# How to inherit application.properties with spring boot multiple modules

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, dependency-properties

I using spring boot multiple modules and i want inherit application.properties from parent . I have parent module :  spring-ecommere-demo and sub module : model , core and security. In parent modules i put some config jdbc look like :

**application.properties** (parent module)

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/BaoTrung
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=123456
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

And in sub module security i specific config look like:

**application-security.properties** (security module)

```
app.jwtSecret= JWTSuperSecretKey
app.jwtExpirationInMs = 604800000
```

And config in Spring Boot application in security module look like :

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "springecommeredemo")
@PropertySources({
        @PropertySource("application-security.properties")
})
```

But when i run it, it throw me exception

Description:

> Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and
>   no embedded datasource could be configured.
>
> Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
>
> Action:
>
> Consider the following:   If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or
>   Derby), please put it on the classpath.   If you have database settings
>   to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it
>   (the profiles dev are currently active).

It mean sub module security can't inherit properties from parent project. How to inherit all properties from parent module. Because i using same database , i don't want config duplicate jdbc in my project. I want inherit common properties.Please help

Comment: This would be easy to implement if you would have a `config-server` that provides configurations to any `microservice` like in this case `security` then it will work. So what you want to do I will create an answer better.

Comment: @JonathanJohx thanks you please help me. If i understand correctly, i need create sub module config-server and dependency it into security ?

Comment: Is your architecture `micro-service` that you are using? right?

Comment: @JonathanJohx Yes. Correctly

Answer (score 5):

You need to add multiple `Properties` can be accessed in Spring, I added duplicated annotation for `@PropertySource` since before `Java 8` if you needed to use multiple instances of the same annotation, they had to be wrapped in a container annotation. With `Java 8`, that's no longer necessary, allowing for cleaner, more readable code.

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "springecommeredemo")
@PropertySource("application.properties")
@PropertySource("application-security.properties")
```

Comment: but when i put @PropertySource("application.properties") in application.class in module security, it throw me exception : can't find application.properties in class path

Comment: @BaoTrungTran - did you keep the properties in the src/main/resources folder itself?

Comment: Yes. I keep application.properties in class path with parent(spring-ecommere-demo) not sub module(security)

Answer (score 2):

I use spring boot 2.5. Let's say that I have a common module and a app module, which uses the common module. If I want to access all the properties defined in the common module properties file, then I will add the following to the top of the app module's properties file.

```
spring.config.import=classpath:common-module.properties
```

You can have any name for that "common-module" properties file.

Answer (score 1):

I found solution this here :
[Maven Multi Module insists on duplicating datasource application.properties in business module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47317674/maven-multi-module-insists-on-duplicating-datasource-application-properties-in-b)

Only create sub-module : example :server-config and run it. In sub module : security add server-config as dependency and run it. It work for me

Comment: This doesn't make sense and needs elaborating further

Answer (score 1):

So I am building about the same framework as yours, here's what worked for me

Add the `classpath` prefix this to your `@PropertySource` annotation

```java
@PropertySource("classpath:application-security.properties") // application-security on root
```

Also,
If the properties are located inside a package just do :

```java
@PropertySource("classpath:/com/my/project/application.properties") // com.my.project package
```

If you want multiple sources, be sure to do the same :

```java
@PropertySources({
    @PropertySource("classpath:xxx.properties"),
    @PropertySource("classpath:/com/my/project/xxx.properties")
})
```