# How to use message.properties file in main project (has two dependency project) in spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have spring boot project A, B, C.

Project A have dependency of B,C.

How to use message.properties with config file in project A, that should be applicable for B,C.

Comment: Take a look at the question about the properties inheritance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58091902/how-to-inherit-application-properties-with-spring-boot-multiple-modules

Comment: @Nikolas, Can you please give me some example for project wise