# How to create per module application.properties in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, multi-module

I have a spring boot project in which there are multiple modules, I want to have each module separate application properties file, but when I added properties file in all modules, it's still picking properties from main application properties file.

Project Structure:

```
|-- Dockerfile
|-- build.gradle
|-- modules
|   |-- application
|   |   |-- build.gradle
|   |   `-- src
|   |       `-- main
|   |           |-- java
|   |           |   `-- org
|   |           |       `-- example
|   |           |           |-- CoreApplication.java
|   |           `-- resources
|   |               |-- application-beta.properties
|   |               |-- application-dev.properties
|   |               |-- application-local.properties
|   |               |-- application-prod.properties
|   |               |-- application-test.properties
|   |               `-- application.properties
|   |-- config-management
|   |   |-- build.gradle
|   |   `-- src
|   |       `-- main
|   |           |-- java
|   |           |   `-- org
|   |           |       `-- example
|   |           |           `-- controller
|   |           |               `-- TestController.java
|   |           `-- resources
|   |               |-- application-beta.properties
|   |               |-- application-dev.properties
|   |               |-- application-local.properties
|   |               |-- application-prod.properties
|   |               |-- application-test.properties
|   |               `-- application.properties
`-- settings.gradle
```

`application.properties` in config module

```
config.hello=hello-from-config
```

`application.properties` in application module

```
config.hello=hello-from-application
```

`TestController.java` in config module

```java
@RestController
public class TestController {
    @Value("${config.hello}")
    private String hello;

    @GetMapping("hello")
    public String get() {
        return hello;
    }
}
```

After calling `/hello` api, response: `hello-from-application`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to inherit application.properties with spring boot multiple modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58091902/how-to-inherit-application-properties-with-spring-boot-multiple-modules)

Comment: No, because in that case, I have to put my config properties in application module. But I want to keep those in config module itself.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a complete answer to your question but more a list of advices I think you should follow when designing your multi-module application project.

- With spring many things are easier to configure with `@Configuration` beans. On many occasions, you'll be forced to have such beans to configure specific functionalities. These configuration beans are also a great way of including a configuration of one module in another.
- What I do is the following - each module has one main `@Configuration` bean. This bean `@Import`s all other `@Configuration` beans inside your module, as well as, loads the properties file and imports the main `@Configuration` beans of the modules and maybe external dependencies your module depends on.
- You should remember that spring, and java in general uses the classloader to load these `.properties` files that you have in the `resources` folders. The way you have organized the `.property` files currently they override each other; depending on how spring boot works the classloader will either load the first `*.properties` file it encounters, or maybe, your extra property files won't even make it into the shaded jar file. As a solution, use packages. Each module should have all of its stuff in a specific package, this includes the configuration files.
- Do not include environment-related configuration files in your application source code. Move it to your deployment procedures. You can have samples of these environment-related files in your `/docs` or `/distribution` folder in your project, but have them here as documentation and not as actual configurations used in these environments. In 99% of the cases, environment-related configurations should be stored separately from your compiled application, the way you have it now they are compiled into the application itself.

Hope this was helpful.

P.S.
Once you organize the config files in the manner I describe, you may still end up fighting a battle against Spring's property file loader(don't remember the exact name), but that's a separate topic, and there are already many questions on that topic here.